# Mule Error, Only owner thread can write to message still occures with http module

Tags: java, multithreading, mule, mule-component, mule-cluster

I have the next error in production cluster Mule 3.6. it occur sometimes during the day, but does not reach detect the original cause.

> 2015-11-17 08:01:54,819 ERROR [org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy] - Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Only owner thread can write to message: Thread[[ComponentAA-PRD-v3.2.1.RELEASE].HTTP_Listener_Config.worker.130,5,main]/Thread[[ComponentAA-PRD-v3.2.1.RELEASE].http.listener(9) SelectorRunner,5,main] 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only owner thread can write to message: Thread[[axcess-document-platform-PRD-v3.2.1.RELEASE].HTTP_Listener_Config.worker.130,5,main]/Thread[[axcess-document-platform-PRD-v3.2.1.RELEASE].http.listener(9) SelectorRunner,5,main]
>       at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.newException(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1665) ~[?:?]
>       at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.checkMutable(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1651) ~[?:?]
>       at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.assertAccess(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1580) ~[?:?]
>       at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.setExceptionPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1003) ~[?:?]
>       at org.mule.exception.TemplateMessagingExceptionStrategy.handleException(TemplateMessagingExceptionStrategy.java:79) ~[?:?]
>       at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$3$1.execute(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:105) ~[?:?]
>       at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.executeCallback(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:117) ~[?:?]
>       at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.access$000(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:23) ~[?:?]
>       at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$3.responseSentWithFailure(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:100) ~[?:?]
>       at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate$1.responseSendFailure(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:114) ~[?:?]
>       at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ResponseCompletionHandler.failed(ResponseCompletionHandler.java:153) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.AsyncQueueRecord.notifyFailure(AsyncQueueRecord.java:110) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.onWriteFailure(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:489) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.processAsync(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:400) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:108) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) ~[?:?]
>       at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102) ~[?:?]
>       at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:75) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:414) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:383) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:347) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:278) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565) ~[?:?]
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545) ~[?:?]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_80]

Comment: Does the error occur for any artifacts (mule-app) or only for a specific artifact?

Comment: Issue registered in Mule-jira: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8159

Answer (score 0):

That issue was reported as https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8961 and it is fixed since Mule 3.7.3 and 3.8.0.